# How to install patched Paypal module in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I am not an expert of Drupal, but I am trying to configure a site with Drupal Commerce, and in particular, the PayPal module.

I need the following two patches:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2415489
https://www.drupal.org/node/2415501
that, if I understood correctly they are not merged into the paypal module yet.

So, what I did is to manually download the PayPal module, manually apply the patches (unfortunately they conflict each other, so I applied one with the `patch` command and the other by manually diff the files) and I tar.gz everything.

The resultant module is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7968745/commerce_paypal-7.x.2.3.tar.gz

Now, if I try to install this module I get the following error:

```
Unable to create directory 'temporary://update-extraction-bde81194/.'
```

[image: error]

But if I try to install any other module, it works.

BTW: I don't know if this is relevant or not. Before installing my custom-made module, I disabled and uninstalled the PayPal module, but if now I look for the modules in my Drupal installation I still find the PayPal module (but disabled)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the temporary directory is configured at `admin/config/media/file-system` is writable.

In my case `/tmp` is writable, as per the settings in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't this apply also to "official" modules, i.e. the one I copy the link directly from the Drupal website? because they work. Furthermore, I tried to move from `/tmp` to `tmp` as I'm using an hosting provider

Comment: Any ideas? Should I wait that those patches get integrated into the main code, so I can directly update the module? Official modules get installed without any problem, so I don't think it is a problem of file system permisssion